# USB RF Videotransmission, is it possible?

Tags: usb, rf, processor, video-transmitter

I am thinking about building my next rc plane complete from scratch. I wanted to do the programming by myself, so I have the problem, that I can't use any 5.8Ghz video transmitter because I can't implement those.
Now I want to build the transmitter and receiver by myself and it shall be connected to the PC by USB. But where do I start, if I want to build such a device? What kind of processor do I need? I also can't use Arduino because all types are to slow.

Hope you can help me

Thanks

ChopStick

Comment: You might barely manage to sample analog video with a fast MCU or a discrete ADC feeding a USB FIFO, but why not just use an analog monitor or television?

Comment: I can't programm with that kind of signal and I wanted to go with object tracking ... later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 900MHz band has sufficient bandwidth to support video links. You could compress the video, and merely transmit the changes. Assuming line-of-sight, with 1MegaHertz bandwidth (for compressed data) at 900MHz (wavelength 1/3 meter) over distance of 3,000 meters (2 miles), your transmit power must be

-174dBm/sqrt(Hz)

+60dB sqrt(Hz) for 1MHz pixel rate

+20dB SNR (picture will be noisy)

+10dB Receiver LNA NoiseFloor and losses from Antenna to LNA

+102dB PathLoss (22 + 10*log10{ (3,000/0.33)^2  }

total -174 + 192dB = +18dBm or 2*6mW = 32mW = 0.032watts

That analysis is MIXING several concepts and limits, being more oriented to analog-video RF-channel transmission.

Suppose we digitize the video channel, likely necessary for image compression. One question arises about coding-gain, or bit-error-correction(BEC); this BEC allows dropping the SNR from +20dB to +5dB. Yet the #bits has to grow, to support whatever dynamic range you wish, pushing the SNR back up because a dense constellation (dense I/Q magnitude/phase points) tolerates less random noise and less multipath.

The major question remains: how much complexity, how steep a learning curve do you desire?

Comment: That's a very good answer, thanks buddy, but I was actually asking for how to implement a curcuit like that into an USB device and what kind of electrical parts I need for that device.

Comment: You'd expressed doubt about 5GHz methods; I provided insights for 900MHz methods, including what TX power is needed. The system design for electronic devices usually included successfully moving data, whether only 2' in an internet router PCB or 3,000 meters for a RC airplane control link. What image rate, what resolution, what additive noise, what compression, can you tolerate?

Comment: I wanted to have a 1280×720 solution, 30FPS, about 400kb per picture, but I think I can scale it down to 80-100kp per picture. But basically I need to know where to look for the right parts for the controller for the device, I know about programming (C++ & Java).

Comment: I found many books, but none of them actually says how to build a usb device, so I need advice for the chip and how to program it.